How to make "hg clone" with hggit use the .netrc for HTTP authentication?
I have a remote Git repository that is to be accessed via HTTPS with basic auth, whose credentials are properly configured in my ~/.netrc, e.g.
$ cat ~/.netrc
machine example.com login example-user password ***

A git clone works fine:
$ git clone https://example.com/some-repo

However, trying the same with Mercurial using the hggit extension fails with:
$ hg clone git+https://example.com/some-repo
abort: http authorization required for https://example.com/some-repo

Note that hg clone git+https://... works without issues on remote Git repositories that have no HTTP auth.

How do I make hg clone (with hggit) use my .netrc credentials?
The the above is impossible, how am I supposed to provide my HTTP auth credentials to hg clone (with hggit)?


Does Mercurial use .netrc for authorization? I couldn't find any information about it so it seems it doesn't. For Git a lot info can be found in search engines.

Does hg clone git+https://user:password@example.com/some-repo work? If not may be this could help: https://wiki.openjdk.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51282041#Mercurial-PersonalAccessToken ?
